# What type of jellyfish is this

Tags: zoology, species-identification

I have been swimming in the seas around Minorca and saw a jellyfish I had not seen before.

I have tried to find it and have (eventually) found 1 single picture of the jellyfish.

[image]

The problem I have is, the image is from one of these "buy our picture" website and offers no information about the creature.

What type of Jellyfish is this and can I assume from the picture that it does not actually sting humans?

I have researched, and viewed sites like (As well as Google/Bing images)

http://www.holidays-majorca.co.uk/trips/beaches/types-jellyfish-around-majorca
http://www.seafriends.org.nz/indepth/jellyfish.htm (I know, it's NZ but I'm looking everywhere I can)
http://www.glaucus.org.uk/Moonjell.htm
http://www.whatsthatfish.com/browse/tags/limit/Jellyfish
http://www.imenorca.com/en/entrada-de-blog/jellyfish-minorca
http://www.menorca-tips.com/EN-jellyfish.html
http://www.mcsuk.org/downloads/wildlife/Jellyfishguide.pdf

Comment: Same species? Found yesterday on Palm Island, Dubai![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UelM.jpg)

Comment: https://jellywatch.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually, I've stumbled upon [an article](http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20130731/local/cigar-jellyfish-returns.480195) which calls it a cigar jellyfish.

Further research even shows a very empty entry on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olindias_phosphorica) about it, which consists of the single line entry:

> The cigar jellyfish (Olindias phosphorica) is a species of jellyfish from the Central and East Atlantic, and the Mediterranean Sea, including off Malta.[2]

Also an [interesting article](http://oceania.research.um.edu.mt/jellyfish/articles/Rare%20species%20reported%20in%20Malta%20jellyfish%20spotting%20campaign%20-%20August%208,%202010.pdf) about it being 'rare' in Malta (despite the above information)

[image]